# Python: pyxform convert csv to xls

Tags: python, django, excel, csv

I have a system in Django that is used to store survey data. Some of the survey data were lost and now I need to recover those data. The data are backed up in **csv and xls format**.

A model like below saves the data in different formats.

```
class Forms(models.Model):
    xform = models.ForeignKey(XForm, related_name="fshistory")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    xls = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, null=True)
    json = models.TextField(default=u'')
    description = models.TextField(default=u'', null=True)
    xml = models.TextField()
    id_string = models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=255)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=u'')
    version = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=u'')
```

The **xml and json** stored in above model have been generated using **pyxform**(https://github.com/XLSForm/pyxform).

```
from pyxform.builder import create_survey_from_xls

survey = create_survey_from_xls(xls_file)
xml = survey.to_xml()
```

The problem is that I have only been able to convert the **xls** files using pyxform into xml. Other data that are stored in **csv format** are cannot be directly converted to xml so I need to convert them into xls first.

So, I need to know whether pyxform has any module to convert csv to xls, or is there any other way possible to do so and obtain a proper xml file?

I did try other techniques to convert the csv to xls like:

```
    for filename in os.listdir(xls_directory):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(xls_directory,filename)):
            if filename.endswith(".csv"):
                wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
                ws = wb.active
                xls_file = open(os.path.join(xls_directory, filename))

                reader = csv.reader(xls_file, delimiter=str(u';').encode('utf-8'))
                for row in reader:
                    ws.append(row)

                wb.save(''+filename.replace('.csv', '.xls'))
                print('File saved')
```

If I use `survey = create_survey_from_xls(xls_file)` in the xls files created from above code, it throws an error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/kobocat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/kobocat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/kobocat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/kobocat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/sanip/naxa/source/fieldsight/onadata/apps/fsforms/management/commands/create_xform_history.py", line 82, in handle
    survey = create_survey_from_xls(xls_file)
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/kobocat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxform/builder.py", line 295, in create_survey_from_xls
    excel_reader = SurveyReader(path_or_file)
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/kobocat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxform/xls2json.py", line 1176, in __init__
    path, warnings=self._warnings, file_object=self._file_object)
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/kobocat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxform/xls2json.py", line 1090, in parse_file_to_json
    workbook_dict, default_name, default_language, warnings)
  File "/home/sanip/.virtualenvs/kobocat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxform/xls2json.py", line 327, in workbook_to_json
    u"The survey sheet is either empty or missing important "
pyxform.errors.PyXFormError: The survey sheet is either empty or missing important column headers.
```

Can someone provide me with some idea here?

Comment: "this does not give me the xls in proper format as required by pyxform" - What format does pyxform require?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I don't know exactly the format of the file required by pyxform, but both the files (supported by pyxform and generated xls) are identical to look at. But an error is being seen which I have included in the question.

Comment: Looks like it expects the sheet to be named "survey".

Comment: I don't think the sheet name would make any difference. Also, the error is of `pyxform` itself. https://github.com/XLSForm/pyxform/blob/master/pyxform/xls2json.py **workbook_to_json** method of pyxform is throwing this error(you can see it from that link).

Comment: Isn't that what this line is doing? `for row in workbook_dict.get(constants.SURVEY, [])`

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes you are right. I did check the xls files supported by pyxform and they contain the sheet name as `survey`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error. It would be nice if you could post this suggestion as an answer so that I can accept it. It can be used by other users too, if they are involved in pyxforms.